# How to debug VCL in varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

How can I `print a log` in VCL?

Can I print log info on screen?

Can I do like this?

```
sub vcl_recv {
  ....
  log.info(req.http.host); // can i write a log here?
  ....
}
```

Comment: Check if you are asking for `varnishd -Cf file_name`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can see URL with requested URLs varnishlog utility (it able to write log files)

```
varnishlog -i RxURL
```

Or output some info to syslog with vmod std and syslog function for <s>Varnish 3.x https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_std.html#syslog</s> Varnish 5.1 https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.1/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#func-syslog

Example:

```
import std;

sub vcl_recv {
  ...
  std.syslog(180, "RECV: " + req.http.host + req.url);
  ...
}
```

Or with C-snippet on Varnish 2.x https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleSyslog

Comment: VCC-compiler failed:Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
('input' Line 49 Pos 9)
        std.syslog(180, "RECV: " + req.http.host + req.url);

Comment: Ok, yes, we forgot to import std vmod functions with:
`import std;` https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vmod.html

Comment: Thanks. I can see the log in file /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Adding comment for later editing: varnish vmod_std 3.0 at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vmod_std.html#syslog and 4.0 at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#void-syslog-int-string-list

Answer (score 18):

Using a [vcl config file](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_Basics.html), import the additional included "standard library", which includes a bunch of utility functions:

```
import std;

# To 'varnishlog'
std.log("varnish log info:" + req.host);

# To syslog
std.syslog( LOG_USER|LOG_ALERT, "There is serious trouble");
```

v6.x - https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vmod_generated.html#void-log-string-s

v5.x - https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.0/reference/vmod_std.generated.html?#func-log

v4.x - https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vmod_std.generated.html?#func-log

v3.x - https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vmod_std.html#log

See also `man varnishlog`